# How to make section element in css to full width

Tags: html, css, web, width

In the image, red circled area is my problem:

[image]

Here is the Html/Css.

```css
section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutSec">
  <div>
    <h1>Here is about Sec</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have some `margin` on the `section` element, or you have some `padding` on a containing element.  Remember that the browser has a default stylesheet, so if you're not overridding it with a [css reset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/), then there are some styles already present and affecting your layout.  I recommend adding the line `margin: 0;` to your `section`, and then traversing parents or checking in the dev tools to see if a parent element has a padding that is pushing the layout.

Comment: Yes your tip worked for me. I set "margin:0!important" and the "!imporatant" did the job. Thanks @anied

Comment: @waterbrain -- glad to help, and glad your layout is working for you now!  Be careful with that `!important` modifier-- its very powerful, and easy to overuse.  There's definitely cases in which it is needed, though.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```css
section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
}
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutSec">
  <div>
    <h1>Here is about Sec</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Try It Once

Comment: it worked for me setting padding and margin to 0 with !important.